# Error using OR function in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am using Excel Formula `OR` in an Excel formula and am little surprised the way it is behaving.

I am using the following Excel formula :

```
=IF(OR(ISERROR(funct(A1:A5)), funct(A1,A5)=0), "ERROR", funct(A1,A5))
```

My understanding was that, if `ISERROR(funct(A1:A5))` `True(or False)`, the result of OR operation would be True(or False).

In my experiment, I was expecting the answer to be **"ERROR"** as the `ISERROR(funct(A1:A5))` results in `true`.

But I am getting `#VALUE!` error.  Any Idea what could be wrong. Or if I can rephrase the formula to make it work.

Thanks

Comment: `OR()` doesn't short-circuit, so even if the first argument is TRUE it will still evaluate the following arguments. Attempting to evaluate `funct(A1,A5)` is likely the cause of the #VALUE error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're missing a close bracket.

Try this:

```
=IF(OR(ISERROR(funct(A1:A5)), func(A1,A5)=0), "ERROR", func(A1,A5))
```

Comment: I am sorry, There was a typo in the question. No, I donot think that could be the reason

Comment: Then I'll need to see how func/funct is/are defined.

Comment: func() is quiet a big function unfortunately. So my idea was, if there is a OR function, if 1st operand turns out be true or false, is the second operand calculated or computed ?

Comment: If you use "Evaluate Formula" (under Formulas in 2007/2010) you can step through the calculation to see where you are getting the issue.

Comment: @KiranChandrashekhar `if there is a OR function, if 1st operand turns out be true or false, is the second operand calculated or computed ?` - yes it **does**, as suggested in the above comment to your request. You may check that using evaluator as well.

Comment: Not sure why this is the accepted answer.  I think Tim Williams' answer is the correct one.

Answer (score 5):

```
=IF(ISERROR(funct(A1:A5)),"ERROR",IF(funct(A1:A5)=0,"ERROR",funct(A1:A5)))
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend Tim's answer but if `func()` is a large function, as you say, then you might want to minimise the number of times it's used. I'm assuming that the same function should be invoked throughout the formula, i.e. func(A1:A5)

In Excel 2007 or later you could use IFERROR function:

`=IFERROR(IF(func(A1:A5)=0,"ERROR",func(A1:A5)),"ERROR")`

or in earlier versions you could force func(A1:A5) to give an error when equal to zero by dividing 1 by func(A1:A5):

`=IF(ISERROR(1/func(A1:A5)),"ERROR",func(A1:A5))`

Edit: Taking that one step further you could combine both of those approaches in Excel 2007 or later so that you only need to call func once:

`=IFERROR(1/(1/func(A1:A5)),"ERROR")`

Answer (score 0):

`=IF(OR(ISERROR(funct(A1:A5)), funct(A1,A5)=0), "ERROR", func(A1,A5))` - close look at your formula resulted in the suggestion: `funct(A1,A5)=0` and `func(A1,A5)` are really **different** functions, or this is a **typo** in your formula? Perhaps that's the case.